# Finding generator matrix for binary linear code given parity check matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coding-theory

I have a parity check matrix for a binary linear code V below:

$$    H = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

I want to find a generator matrix for V. Is anything different than just converting the parity matrix to the generator since I'm trying to find one for 'V'? As in, put $H$ in standard form to get $[I\mid A]$, then $G = [-A^T \mid I]$?

Steps I did: R3 = R1 + R3
$$ H = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
R1 = R1 + R3
$$ H = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

R2 = R2 + R1
$$ H = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

So the parity matrix is now in the form [I3 | A ] where A = $$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$G = [-A^T \mid I] = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Is this correct?

Edit: $$G = [-A^T \mid I] = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: You can [post mathematical notation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) using MathJax and $\LaTeX$.  I'll format the matrix $H$ for you (unless someone beats me to it!) to give you the idea.

Comment: Oh thank you! Much easier to read.

Comment: The final matrix $G$ is wrong. $-A^T$ is wrong and you don't have the identity in the right block.

Comment: Check the last edit, is that correct? I was following an example I found which seemed to have $-A^T$ wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think the last edit is correct.
But for the row operation part I would do

R1 = R1 + R3, R2 = R2 + R3

and then swap R1 and R3 to get an [I3|A]

Answer (score 1):

The formulas being used are incorrect.

Generator Matrix

G = [I | A]

Parity Matrix
H = [ -A Transpose | I]